# Unable to handle alerts in chromedriver using selenium webdriver 3.1

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, alert

Unable to handle alerts in ChromeDriver 2.33 and Selenium Webdriver 3.1. Tried driver.switchTo().alert(), even if alert is present the function returns false.

> **EDIT:** Please find the code trial below...

```
try { driver.switchTo().alert(); return true; }
catch(NoAlertPresentException ex) { return false; } catch(Exception e) { return false; }
```

This code return false in chromedriver even if there is an alert popup available in the webpage for login credentials.

Comment: Your code trials and the error stack trace please.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials (`not as a comment`) for a effective analysis.

Answer (score 0):

To handle `Alert` through `WebDriver` you can use any of the following code blocks :

- Wait and Accept :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
  ```
- Wait, Switch and Accept :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  ```

Comment: Hi Deb,                                                                                                                       Thanks for the reply, driver.switchTo().alert().accept() throws NoAlerteException for chromedriver.

Comment: If `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` throws `NoAlerteException` perhaps it's not an **Alert**. You can Accept the Answer and raise a new question with your new requirement.